# How do I use variable to represent method?

Tags: python

example code of the problem:
[image: example code of the problem] \
error:
[image: the error]

I try to do this to reduce repetition of my code but it doesn't work. I want to use take variable to represent either pop or serve. Is there a way to make this work? This might looks unnecessary but the real code I am having problem is quite long and it looks very repetitive if I put them in if else block. Instead of putting the return statement into if else block, I want to set a variable of the method instead.

Comment: Answer: yes, there is a way. Maybe you also want to ask a better question after you included your code as code. Also: beware of the [mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Why don't you simply `return` inside the `if`?

Comment: Wow, you posted another image of text after you were told not to do that...

Comment: Do not post images. We cannot copy them or run them. A high quality question makes it easy for us to test and post high quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

**For other questions always provide code in text rather than a bitmap, so it can be copied and pasted.**

All you need is obj.func as the variable.

```
class A:
    def func_1(self):
        print('hi')

class B:
    def func_2(self):
        print('hello there')

def test(one_or_zero):
    if one_or_zero:
        obj = A()
        func = obj.func_1
    else:
        obj = B()
        func = obj.func_2
    func()
    return

test(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to give the function linked to the object.

```
if one_or_zero == 1:
    obj = Stack()
    take = obj.pop
elif one_or_zero == 0:
    obj = Queue()
    take = obj.serve
else:
    ...
return take()
```